# Elasticsearch - Efficiency of search across multiple types

Tags: mapping, elasticsearch

Let me explain my question with an example.
Let's say I have three different type of document with some common fields i.e `book, song, magazin`

- ***Book*** has `name, author, publisher, pageNumber` etc.
- ***Song*** has `name, singer, publisher, length` etc.
- ***Magazin*** has `name, company, publisher, pageNumber` etc.

As you see *name* and *publisher* fields are common fields for all the three types of documents.
*pageNumber* is feature of both ***Magazin*** and ***Book***. And rest of the fields are independent from other types of documents.

I will store these data on same index. I can store these data either,

- with a single type such as ***Object*** which has a `category` (***Book***, ***Song***, ***Magazin***) field in it. I'm giving mapping details when index first created. So, in this option book will have length field but it will be empty, since its not a Book feature.
- or three types of documents on _type field.

My queries and facets will be on common fields. Which of the following approaches would have lesser query and facet times?

Is `/index/book,song,magazin/ -d {myQuery}` more efficient than 
`/index/object/ -d {myQuery && (category = book || category = song || category = magazin)}` ?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: The only way to know is to generate some test data and benchmark it yourself. Without doing this you will be left with nothing more than a religious decision, based on faith and not fact, led down this or that path by whatever sort of proselyte happens along to appeal to you first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Elasticsearch's type concept does not exist in Lucene.

When indexing documents, the document's type gets indexed. Then, when searching on just certain types, Elasticsearch will implicitly add a filter on the indexed type to your query.

Thus, with your last approach, you would have your `category`-filter *in addition* to the implicit `_type:object`-filter. Essentially, you are not gaining anything by not using Elasticsearch's types here.

Comment: this is super helpful to know